# Will I do true genocide if I spare Monster Kid?

Tags: undertale

Will I do true genocide if I spare Monster Kid? Will I get the true genocide ending? I farmed everymonster in the Ruins, Snowdin, and Waterfall except Monster Kid.

Comment: Is there a reason why you thought it would still work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**. Sparing monster kid will place you back on a neutral path, triggering the normal Undyne fight in the next room, instead of the Undyne the Undying fight there.